# SQL Query: how to return only the first and last instance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table that shows the status of each case with multiple jobs being performed simultaneously, I would like to have the results displayed so that it only shows the first and last instance.  (Mainly I want to know when the job was first started and what's its last known status).

I've managed to get the results with 2 similar min, max, and group by queries joined by an UNION function.  But is there a simpler way?

However, would it be possible to display the 2 instances on one line instead of 2 separate lines?  because the date from the first instance will be the start date and the last instance will be the end date, and i don't really care about the first status because it's always pending, i just want to know what's the last known status

1st table shows unfiltered results and 2nd table is desired results (but if we can combine the first and last instance on one line that'd be even better)

```
ID  Status      Date       Job  Note
1   pending     1-Jul       A   abc
1   pending     2-Jul       A   xyz
1   pending     2-Jul       A   abc
1   done        3-Jul       B   xyz
1   done        4-Jul       A   abc
2   pending     1-Jul       A   abc
2   done        2-Jul       A   xyz
2   done        2-Jul       A   abc
2   pending     3-Jul       C   xyz
2   pending     4-Jul       C   xyz
2   pending     5-Jul       C   xyz
2   pending     6-Jul       C   xyz
3   pending     2-Jul       D   xyz
3   done        3-Jul       D   abc
3   pending     4-Jul       D   abc
3   pending     1-Jul       E   xyz
3   done        3-Jul       E   xyz

ID  Status      Date       Job  Note
1   pending     1-Jul       A   abc
1   done        3-Jul       B   xyz
1   done        4-Jul       A   abc
2   pending     1-Jul       A   abc
2   done        2-Jul       A   abc
2   pending     3-Jul       C   xyz
2   pending     6-Jul       C   xyz
3   pending     2-Jul       D   xyz
3   pending     4-Jul       D   abc
3   pending     1-Jul       E   xyz
3   done        3-Jul       E   xyz
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Can you explain what you need more clearly?   "only shows the first and last instance"?    Per what?   ID?    Job?   If your second data sample is a desired result, I don't understand how you would get those results from the data in the first sample.

Comment: per Job and ID.  For instance, both job A and B have been assigned to ID1, Job A was started on July 1st, the last record we have for A under ID 1 is on the 4th of July.  So we want to display both the first row from the first table and the 5th row.  I hope that's more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to use `ROW_NUMBER` function twice in ascending and descending order to get first and last rows of each group. See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e9ff5/2/0)

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
  SELECT
    ID
    ,Status
    ,dt
    ,Job
    ,Note
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Job ORDER BY dt ASC) AS rnASC
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Job ORDER BY dt DESC) AS rnDESC
  FROM T
)
SELECT 
    ID
    ,Status
    ,dt
    ,Job
    ,Note
FROM CTE
WHERE rnAsc=1 OR rnDesc=1
ORDER BY ID, Job, dt
```

This variant would scan through the whole table, calculate row numbers and discard those rows that don't satisfy the filter.

The second variant is to use `CROSS APPLY`, which may be more efficient, if (a) your main table has millions of rows, (b) you have a small table with the list of all `ID`s and `Job`s, (c) the main table has appropriate index. In this case instead of reading all rows of the main table you can do index seek for each `(ID, Job)` (two seeks, one for first row plus one for the last row).

Comment: works like  a charm, it's a lot faster than my original union query. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.JOB, A.STATUS, B.START_DATE, CASE WHEN A.STATUS = 'done' THEN C.END_DATE ELSE NULL AS END_DATE
FROM <JOBS_TABLE> A
JOIN (SELECT ID, JOB, MIN(DATE) AS START_DATE FROM <JOBS_TABLE> GROUP BY ID, JOB) B
ON A.ID = B.ID
AND A.JOB = B.JOB
JOIN (SELECT ID, JOB, MAX(DATE) AS END_DATE FROM <JOBS_TABLE GROUP BY ID, JOB) C
ON A.ID= C.ID
AND A.JOB = C.JOB
AND A.DATE = C.END_DATE
```

You'll need to replace < JOBS_TABLE > with whatever your table name is. Ideally, this should combine the data from the  first and last rows for each distinct set of ID and JOB values. If the job is not finished, it will not show an END_DATE.

Comment: hmm, it's giving me 3 errors, 1) incorrect syntax on line 1 near keyword 'as', 2) incorrect syntax near 'B' on line 3, and 3) incorrect syntax near 'C' on line 6

Comment: There needs to be an END after the NULL on the first line. Can you show me the exact structure of what you tried to run? The answer I posted is pseudo-code because I don't know the exact name of your table etc.

Comment: Depending on what DB you're using, you may need an AS after the ) and before the B and after the ) and before the C

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's much wrong with your UNION idea.  Is this what you have?

select id, job, status, max(date), job, note, 'max' as type from test1 group by job UNION
select id, job, status, min(date), job, note, 'min' as type from test1 group by job;

Comment: yes, but i was looking for a more efficient way : )

Comment: Make sure to have an index on the date column.